# C#: Converting string to datetime

Tags: c#, string, datetime

How would I convert this format of a string to datetime. Here's the format:

**27-02-14 12:02:03 AM**

I tried using the Convert.ToDateTime and it threw an exception

Also tried this:

```
DateTime dtFrom = DateTime.ParseExact(fromDate_TAtab, "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss",    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Look at `DateTime.ParseExact` (and look at the related questions).

Comment: Exception it threw would help

Comment: Can you show exactly what you did? Was it literally `Convert.ToDateTime("27-02-14 12:02:03 AM")`? What is your computer's locale / language?

Comment: ok so I tried this and I'm still getting an exception. 

DateTime dtFrom = DateTime.ParseExact(fromDate_TAtab, "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); @JonSkeet

Comment: Yes I just put the string inside the conversion exactly as you have done there @CompuChip

Comment: Try this: 
DateTime dt =  DateTime.Parse(str, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB").DateTimeFormat);

Comment: @kknaguib: That's not your format - you're using a 12-hour clock and an AM/PM specified, so "dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss tt".